# SwiftUI: Set a Published value in an ObservableObject from the UI (Picker, etc.)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, picker, observedobject

> ## Update:
>
> **This question is already solved** (see responses below). The correct way to do this is to get your `Binding` by projecting the
> `ObservableObject` For example, `$options.refreshRate`.

## TLDR version:

How do I get a SwiftUI `Picker` (or other API that relies on a local `Binding`) to immediately update my `ObservedObject`/`EnvironmentObject`. Here is more context...

## The scenario:

Here is something I consistently need to do in every SwiftUI app I create...

- I always make some class that stores any user preference (let's call this class `Options` and I make it an `ObservableObject`.
- Any setting that needs to be consumed is marked with `@Published`
- Any view that consumes this brings it in as a `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` and subscribes to changes.

This all works quite nicely. The trouble I always face is how to set this from the UI. From the UI, here is usually what I'm doing (and this should all sound quite normal):

- I have some SwiftUI view like `OptionsPanel` that drives the `Options` class above and allows the user to choose their options.
- Let's say we have some option defined by an enum:

```swift
enum RefreshRate {
    case low, medium, high
}
```

Naturally, I'd choose a `Picker` in SwiftUI to set this... and the `Picker` API requires that my selection param be a `Binding`. **This is where I find the issue...**

## The issue:

To make the `Picker` work, I usually have some local `Binding` that is used for this purpose. But, ultimately, I don't care about that local value. What I care about is immediately and instantaneously broadcasting that new value to the rest of the app. The moment I select a new refresh rate, I'd like *immediately* know that instant about the change. The `ObservableObject` (the `Options` class) object does this quite nicely. But, I'm just updating a local `Binding`. What I need to figure out is how to immediately translate the `Picker`'s state to the `ObservableObject` every time it's changed.

I have a solution that works... but I don't like it. Here is my non-ideal solution:

## The non-ideal solution:

The first part of the solution is quite actually fine, but runs into a snag...

Within my SwiftUI view, rather than do the simplest way to set a `Binding` with `@State` I can use an alternate initializer...

```swift
// Rather than this...
@ObservedObject var options: Options
@State var refreshRate: RefreshRate = .medium

// Do this...
@ObservedObject var options: Options
var refreshRate: Binding<RefreshRate>(
    get: { self.options.refreshRate },
    set: { self.options.refreshRate = $0 }
)
```

So far, this is great (in theory)! Now, my local `Binding` is directly linked to the `ObservableObject`. All changes to the `Picker` are immediately broadcast to the entire app.

But this doesn't actually work. And this is where I have to do something very messy and non-ideal to get it to work.

The code above produces the following error:

```
Cannot use instance member 'options' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Here my my (bad) workaround. It works, but it's awful...

The `Options` class provides a `shared` instance as a static property. So, in my options panel view, I do this:

```swift
@ObservedObject var options: Options = .shared // <-- This is still needed to tell SwiftUI to listen for updates
var refreshRate: Binding<RefreshRate>(
    get: { Options.shared.refreshRate },
    set: { Options.shared.refreshRate = $0 }
)
```

In practice, this actually kinda works in this case. I don't really need to have multiple instances... just that one. So, as long as I always reference that shared instance, everything works. But it doesn't feel well architected.

So... *does anyone have a better solution?* This seems like a scenario EVERY app on the face of the planet has to tackle, so it seems like someone must have a better way.

(I am aware some use an `.onDisapear` to sync local state to the `ObservedObject` but this isn't ideal either. This is non-ideal because I value having *immediate* updates for the rest of the app.)

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Declare your `Options` as `class Options: ObservableObject { @Published var name ....}` and 
 use this `options` model directly in your `Picker`, like this:  `Picker(selection: $options.name, label: Text("...")) {...}`

Comment: Just use “$options.refreshRate” why recreate the wheel?

Comment: We use `@AppStorage` for options not `ObservableObject`. `ObservableObject` is used for holding the array of model structs in `@Published` properties.

Comment: Thanks!  `$options.refreshRate` was exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't aware `ObservableObject` had a projected value that returned a `Binding`. I had tried to get this working with no luck, but I think I was trying to project the property vs. the entire `ObservedObject`.. in other words, `options.$refreshRate` vs. `$options.refreshRate`. The local bindings were a workaround since I hadn't found a way to get a `Binding` from an `ObservedObject` till now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is you're trying way, *way*, **way** too hard.

The `ObservedObject` property wrapper can create this `Binding` for you. All you need to say is `$options.refreshRate`.

Here's a test playground for you to try out:

```
import SwiftUI

enum RefreshRate {
    case low, medium, high
}

class Options: ObservableObject {
    @Published var refreshRate = RefreshRate.medium
}

struct RefreshRateEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var options: Options
    
    var body: some View {

                                       // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        Picker("Refresh Rate", selection: $options.refreshRate) {

                                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            Text("Low").tag(RefreshRate.low)
            Text("Medium").tag(RefreshRate.medium)
            Text("High").tag(RefreshRate.high)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var options = Options()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RefreshRateEditor(options: options)
            
            Text("Refresh rate: \(options.refreshRate)" as String)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

It's also worth noting that if you want to create a custom `Binding`, the code you wrote almost works. Just change it to be a computed property instead of a stored property:

```
var refreshRate: Binding<RefreshRate> {
    .init(
        get: { self.options.refreshRate },
        set: { self.options.refreshRate = $0 }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want
to `Set a Published value in an ObservableObject from the UI (Picker, etc.)` in SwiftUI.

There are many ways to do that, I suggest you use a `ObservableObject` class, and use it **directly** wherever you need a binding in a view, such as in a `Picker`.

The following example code shows one way of setting up your code to do that:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// declare your ObservableObject class
class Options: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "Mickey"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var optionModel = Options()  // <-- initialise the model
    let selectionSet = ["Mickey", "Mouse", "Goofy", "Donald"]
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(optionModel.name).foregroundColor(.red)
            Picker("names", selection: $optionModel.name) {  // <-- use the model directly as a $binding
                ForEach (selectionSet, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(value).tag(value)
                }
            }
            Button("Show other view") { showSheet = true }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView(optionModel: optionModel) // <-- pass the model to other view, see also @EnvironmentObject
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @ObservedObject var optionModel: Options  // <-- receive the model
      
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(optionModel.name).foregroundColor(.green) // <-- show updated value
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to have a "useless" intermediate local variable, then use this approach:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     @StateObject var optionModel = Options()  // <-- initialise the model
     let selectionSet = ["Mickey", "Mouse", "Goofy", "Donald"]
     @State var showSheet = false
     
     @State var localVar = ""  // <-- the local var
     
     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Text(optionModel.name).foregroundColor(.red)
             Picker("names", selection: $localVar) {  // <-- using the localVar
                 ForEach (selectionSet, id: \.self) { value in
                     Text(value).tag(value)
                 }
             }
             .onChange(of: localVar) { newValue in
                 optionModel.name = newValue  // <-- update the model
             }
             Button("Show other view") { showSheet = true }
         }
         .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
             SheetView(optionModel: optionModel) // <-- pass the model to other view, see also @EnvironmentObject
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect... This is exactly the way I wanted to do it, but isn't obvious from any docs I've come across that `ObservableObject` had a projected value that returned a `Binding`. I think I was trying to project the published value vs. the entire `ObservedObject`.. in other words, `optionModel.$name` vs. `$optionModel.name`. Thanks! This is exactly the way I wanted it to work but had never found an actual example of.

Comment: This is covered in [WWDC 2020: Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040?time=1046). At 17m25s, Luca talks about it and shows an example. This video is part of the [“Getting started with SwiftUI”](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6ka7o7z9) collection.

Comment: how to be when Its required that optionModel should be ObservedObject ???